# Dynamically apply CSS filter

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, filter

How to dynamically apply CSS filters? I have tried the following for Chrome.

```
image.style = "-webkit-filter: brightness(50%);";
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should set value to the `webkitFilter` property, not to the `style` object. This syntax [will work](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2H3d/):

```
image.style.webkitFilter = "brightness(50%)";
```

If you don't know JavaScript property name, you can reference it by CSS property (like karaxuna suggested, [will work too](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2H3d/1/)):

```
image.style["-webkit-filter"] = "brightness(50%)";
```

Comment: any idea how to combine two filters? say `brightness` and `invert`?

Comment: @MaciejJankowski just separate them with a space, `"brightness(50%) invert()"`: http://jsfiddle.net/bj4p0sxm/

Answer (score 3):

```
image.style["-webkit-filter"] = "brightness(50%)";
```

Answer (score 2):

Add that filter to a class:

```
.bright {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

And toggle that class:

```
image.classList.toggle('bright');
```

Comment: @PavloMykhalov: Well, neither are `-webkit` properties.

Answer (score -1):

1) Check if browser supports css-filters (if needed)
2) Detect if "filter" property needs vendor in current browser and save it
3) Set filter value in format:

```
el.style["-vendor-filter"] = value;
```

or

```
el.style.vendorFilter = value;
```

Check small demo for it: http://codepen.io/malyw/pen/EDnmt
Also you can find large demo showing css filters in action: http://malyw.github.io/css-filters/